# #ifdef doesn't work. But why?

Tags: iphone, conditional-compilation

```
#ifdef doesn't work. But why? 

CGFloat maxScale;

if ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector (scale)] == YES )
{
    NSLog (@"case1");
#define GLOBAL1
}
else 
{
    NSLog (@"case2");
#undef GLOBAL1
}

#ifdef GLOBAL1
NSLog (@"first");
maxScale = 1.0 / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
#else
NSLog (@"second");
maxScale = 1.0;
#endif

#undef GLOBAL1
```

my log:case1, second. But it must be case1, first.

Comment: May wish to fix your formatting.  Will make it easier to read.

Comment: Post the code correctly. It is unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#define`, `#ifdef` are pre-processor macros/conditionals.  That means that the logic contained in them is compiled *before* your code is compiled.  It is not actually part of your code.

[See this guide for learning what pre-processor macros/conditionals are and do.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC29)

---

[EDIT]

This is what your pre-processor sees when it reads your code.

```
#define GLOBAL1
#undef GLOBAL1

#ifdef GLOBAL1
   //...
#else
   //...
#endif

#undef GLOBAL1
```

it **IGNORES** all other code and logic.

This is the actual code output the compiler makes:

```
if ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector (scale)] == YES )
{
    NSLog (@"case1");
}
else 
{
    NSLog (@"case2");
}

// because the pre-processor #undef GLOBAL1
NSLog (@"second");
maxScale = 1.0;
```

The pre-processor code is "executed" telling the compiler *how to* compile, and will *not* be used or run during run-time.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor does not care that the `#define` is inside a coded if statement - it is processed before the code and only cares about other preprocessor definitions.  You can't use `#defines` and other preprocessor commands (such as `#undef`) as code- they will not be hit each time the code enters the conditional branches.